# How to disable connection previously created with `connect`?

Tags: windows, android-studio, batch-file, android-emulator

For instance, then creating connection with emulator and android studio like this

```
cmd /c "cd %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools & adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001"
```

How to switch that connection off by a command from a terminal?

Comment: A quick scan of [their docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) didn't turn up a disconnect option. Did you try `adb --help`? They do mention an `adb kill-server` option.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to run another instance of cmd.exe, or possibly to change directory either: `@Start "" "%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" connect 127.0.0.1:62001`. If you did need to change directory, then use the `/D` option with `Start`, e.g. `@Start "" /D "%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools" "%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" connect 127.0.0.1:62001"`.